# Is it possible to get the maven install plugin to deploy the ejb client jar?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

After years of working with Spring, I'm working on a Java EE 7 application with EJB 3.2 and Maven. One thing I would like is to deploy the EJB Jars separately from the web application so I can develop independently. Including the EJB Jars in the WAR causes the app server to redefine the EJBs in the context of the WAR, which I don't want to happen.

The prescribed method is to have maven create a client jar with this directive:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                <clientExcludes>
                    <clientExclude>**/*Impl.class</clientExclude>
                </clientExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I'm excluding any Impls from the Client JAR.

The issue I'm having is that maven isn't installing the client jar during the install phase.

I can install it manually by doing this:
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=foo-1.0-client.jar -DgroupId=com.awesome -DartifactId=foo -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dclassifier=client

I fiddled around a lot and came up with this

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                    <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                    <clientExcludes>
                        <clientExclude>**/*Impl.class</clientExclude>
                    </clientExcludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>ejb</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

However, this isn't proper. This installs the client as a new artifact, not as the same artifact with classifier client. When you include the client in another application, you are supposed to use ejb-client. This looks in your folder that contains the normal artifact, foo-1.0.jar, and looks for something with classifier client.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.awesome</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <version>${com.awesome.version}</version>
        <type>ejb-client</type>
    </dependency>
```

Stumped here, any ideas?